# wrapAsync return function not result

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

Alright, noob here. Still learning. I don't understand how I get my method to return the result of my `Meteor.wrapAsync` function to the Meteor.call on the client. My `console.log(companies);` in my method produces a function and not the result. What am I not understanding here?

Path: `client.jsx`

```
Meteor.call('getTop100ASX', (error, result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Path: `method.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getTop100ASX'() {
    const aggregateFunc = db.collection('companiesASX').aggregate([{
      $group: {
        _id: {
          location: "$google_maps.geometry_location"
        },
        companies: {
          $addToSet: {
            name: "$company_name"
          }
        }
      }
    }]).toArray((err, result) => {
      return result;
    });

    const companies = Meteor.wrapAsync(aggregateFunc);

    console.log(companies);

    return companies;
  },
});
```

Comment: IIRC, calling `toArray()` without a callback returns a promise. You can return it from your method and that would make your server send the results to the server once the promise is resolved (the aggregation is done).

Comment: Sorry, can you show me what you mean.

Comment: `return db.collection('companiesASX').aggregate([...]).toArray()`

Comment: Jeepers. So easy. Thanks for that.

Comment: @MasterAM even if the solution is quite simple, it would be worth turning it into an answer now, intead of leaving it as a comment. That way people know OP's issue is solved.

Comment: Happy to however, the only option is to vote up your comment. Am I missing something here or did you mean I should put up the solution and mark it as answered.

Comment: @ghybs, Since I simply pulled a snippet from memory and was not certain that it will work, I posted it as a quick comment. The (relatively common, I think) misunderstanding of the use of `wrapAsync` and other options for implementation merit an answer, so now I have added one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrapAsync` wraps a function that would normally take a callback and makes it possible to call that wrapped function on the server in a synchronous fashion, utilizing `fibers` (i.e, takes a function + context and returns a function).

It cannot take some value and magically extract the intended result from it (i.e, in your example, the the `result` from the `toArray` callback).

What you gave it is not a function, but a `Promise` object (that was returned from the call to `toArray`).

Since it already returns a promise, you have several options:

The simpler one is to return that promise (and there is no need for the callback in `toArray()`), since if a Meteor method returns a promise, the server will wait for the promise to resolve and then returns the result to the client.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getTop100ASX'() {
    return db.collection('companiesASX').aggregate([...]).toArray();
  },
});
```

If you need to further process `companies` in the method, you could use async/await, something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  async 'getTop100ASX'() {
    const companies = await db.collection('companiesASX').aggregate([{
      $group: {
        _id: {
          location: "$google_maps.geometry_location"
        },
        companies: {
          $addToSet: {
            name: "$company_name"
          }
        }
      }
    }]).toArray();

    let someResult = sumeFunc(companies);

    return someResult;
  },
});
```

For completeness, in order to use `wrapAsync`, you should have supplied the `toArray` method and the context like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getTop100ASX'() {
    const cursor = db.collection('companiesASX').aggregate([{
      $group: {
        _id: {
          location: "$google_maps.geometry_location"
        },
        companies: {
          $addToSet: {
            name: "$company_name"
          }
        }
      }
    }]);

    // wrap the cursor's `toArray` method and preservs the context
    const syncToArray = Meteor.wrapAsync(cursor.toArray, cursor);

    // and call the wrapped function in a sync manner
    const companies = syncToArray();

    return companies;
  },
});
```